# Mvvmcross: cannot create preference activity

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I am working on a Xamarin project that runs with MvvmCross. I am trying to add a preference view inside Android but I cannot get it to work.

When I try to navigate to the `MvxPreferenceFragment`, I get the following errors:

```
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 12.11 Activity host with ViewModelType PreferenceTest.Droid.Activities.MainPreferenceActivity is not CurrentTopActivity. Showing Activity before showing Fragment for PreferenceTest.Core.ViewModels.Fragments.PreferenceViewModel
An unhandled exception occured.

09-26 13:54:45.753 I/MonoDroid(12779): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779): System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for PreferenceTest.Droid.Activities.MainPreferenceActivity
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewsContainer.GetViewType (System.Type viewModelType) [0x0006a] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Views\MvxViewsContainer.cs:72 
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxAppCompatViewPresenter.ShowHostActivity (MvvmCross.Droid.Views.Attributes.MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross-AndroidSupport\MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat\MvxAppCompatViewPresenter.cs:166 
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat.MvxAppCompatViewPresenter.ShowFragment (System.Type view, MvvmCross.Droid.Views.Attributes.MvxFragmentPresentationAttribute attribute, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x0007d] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross-AndroidSupport\MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat\MvxAppCompatViewPresenter.cs:196 
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewPresenter.<RegisterAttributeTypes>b__39_2 (System.Type view, MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxBasePresentationAttribute attribute, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Views\MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs:188 
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewPresenter.Show (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00055] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Views\MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs:295 
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewDispatcher+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ShowViewModel>b__0 () [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Views\MvxAndroidViewDispatcher.cs:26 
09-26 13:54:45.810 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction (System.Action action, System.Boolean maskExceptions) [0x00020] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Views\MvxAndroidMainThreadDispatcher.cs:20 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request) [0x00014] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Droid\Droid\Views\MvxAndroidViewDispatcher.cs:26 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Core.Navigation.MvxNavigationService+<Navigate>d__32.MoveNext () [0x0003a] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Navigation\MvxNavigationService.cs:179 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at MvvmCross.Core.Navigation.MvxNavigationService+<Navigate>d__40.MoveNext () [0x00078] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\Navigation\MvxNavigationService.cs:293 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at PreferenceTest.Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel+<ExecutePreferences>d__8.MoveNext () [0x00026] in C:\git\PreferenceTest\PreferenceTest\PreferenceTest\PreferenceTest.Core\ViewModels\FirstViewModel.cs:28 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <2e14bb2dd93a405e81838369ed72695b>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <2e14bb2dd93a405e81838369ed72695b>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <2e14bb2dd93a405e81838369ed72695b>:0 
09-26 13:54:45.811 I/MonoDroid(12779):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:a278159c-f25c-4da4-ac29-d4bae0d2de73 (intptr,intptr)
```

This is the code I am trying to run **(for the full code please refer to the github link below)**:
First I created a view inside the xml folder (named preference.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <EditTextPreference android:title="Your Name"
                      android:key="username"
                      android:summary="Please provide your username"></EditTextPreference>
  <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Application Updates"
                      android:defaultValue="false"
                      android:summary="This option if selected will allow the application to check for latest versions."
                      android:key="applicationUpdates" />
  <ListPreference     android:title="Download Details"
                      android:summary="Select the kind of data that you would like to download"
                      android:key="downloadType"
                      android:defaultValue="1"
                      android:entries="@array/listArray"
                      android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
  <CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="prefer wifi"
    android:title="Prefer WiFi" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Also the fragment code:

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainPreferenceActivity), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
[Register(nameof(PreferenceFragment))]
public class PreferenceFragment : MvxPreferenceFragment<PreferenceViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Xml.preferences, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

The call is made with the navigation service:

```
private async void ExecutePreferences()
{
    await _navigationService.Navigate<PreferenceViewModel>();
}
```

**I cannot find what is wrong with this code :).**

Here is also [a github link](https://github.com/kevingoos/PreferenceTest) to the sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue is with the use of the `MvxFragmentPresentation` the first parameter is the type of the `ViewModel` being used for the host activity and not the type of the activity itself. Which in your case would be `MainPreferenceViewModel`.

The next issue is that as you are using the `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter` presenter and so you will need to use `MvxPreferenceFragmentCompat`. `MvxPreferenceFragmentCompat` can be found in the [`MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Preference`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Preference/) NuGet package.

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainPreferenceViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
[Register(nameof(PreferenceFragment))]
public class PreferenceFragment : MvxPreferenceFragmentCompat<PreferenceViewModel>
{
    public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
    {
        SetPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

Lastly you would need to specify a theme for the preferences in your activity

```
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
```

I have gone with a material design theme from the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v14.Preference` but you could have also used one of the other ones:

- `@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay`
- `@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14`

See [pull request](https://github.com/kevingoos/PreferenceTest/pull/1) for full details of changes.

[image: MvxPreferenceFragmentCompat example]

Comment: Excellent answer!